# generating random numbers and printing them on the console (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

i was working on a simple idea of generating random numbers (from 1 to 100) and printing them on the console using c++ but the problem is that each time i run the program it geberates exactly the same numbers each time, it's random, a single number isn't repeated but the same order of random numbers every time!

here's my code

```
// DigitDisplayer.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int max = 100;
    int min = 1;
    int range = (max - min) + 1;
int randnum;
bool nums[100];
for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(nums); j++)
{
    nums[j] = false;
}
for(int i = 0; i < range; i++)
{
    int randnum = (rand() % range) + 1;
    if(nums[randnum] == false){
        nums[randnum] = true;
        cout<< randnum << "\n\n";
    }
    else {
        int randnum = (rand() % range) + 1;
    }
}
cout<< "DONE!!!\n\n";
system ("pause");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should initialize the random number generator using `srand()` at the beginning of your program.

Comment: As an aside, if you're using the precompiled header mechanism the idea is you put iostream and cstdlib inside stdafx.h then the compiler can reuse the loaded headers across compiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `srand` to seed `rand` function, otherway it always return same set of numbers.
`time()` function defined in `cstdlib`

check this:

```
// DigitDisplayer.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int max = 100;
    int min = 1;
    int range = (max - min) + 1;
    int randnum;
    bool nums[100];

     srand (time(NULL));
for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(nums); j++)
{
    nums[j] = false;
}
for(int i = 0; i < range; i++)
{
    int randnum = (rand() % range) + 1;
    if(nums[randnum] == false){
        nums[randnum] = true;
        cout<< randnum << "\n\n";
    }
    else {
        int randnum = (rand() % range) + 1;
    }
}
cout<< "DONE!!!\n\n";
system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: I think it's worth highlighting and explaining the change. And do you need to include `<ctime>` or similar too?

Comment: Sorry, updated. (time function defined in cstdlib)

Comment: if it is an answer to your question, please upvote and mark it as an answer.

Comment: i can't vote cuz of my reputation :( but i marked it as best answer!

Answer (score 1):

The random number generator in C++ is actually a pseudo-random sequence generator, that starts from a given seed.

This is done for two reasons:

- it is very difficult to find a true source of random on all machines implementing the C++ library.
- there is a clear need for a random number generator that generates repeatable sequences (for example, if your unit tests rely on random numbers, you want the tests to be repeatable - and receive the same "random numbers").

That is why you have the srand function that provides a "seed" to the random number generation.

If you do not call `srand` or if you call it with the same value, your "random" sequence will always be the same.

If you call it with a varying seed, the resulting sequence will be unique (in practice it probably has a pattern or is predictable - that depends on the implementation).

Answer (score 0):

You need to seed the ranom number generator. Check out [`srand()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/) for how to do that.

All you usually have to do is call `srand()` once somewhere before you use `rand()`. Note that you should call `srand()` with a different value each time you run your program.

For example, using [`time()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/) to seed is the easiest way:

```
int main()
{
     srand(time(NULL));
     .....
     rand();
     .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Computers can't get generate random numbers. Instead they use an algorithm to generate series of numbers that approximate the way that random numbers behave. These algorithms are called psuedo-random number generators (PNRGs). In every case I know of, these PNRGs can be 'seeded' with a number, this determines where the sequence of pseudo-random numbers will begin. If you want to get different results each time you need to seed your PNRG using a number that varies. For most purposes, the system timer will suffice to generate an effectively random series of numbers. `srand(time(NULL))` will do this for you, as others have explained.

By the way: the built-in random number generator in C is *terrible*. It is not fit for use in all but the most casual of settings; if you want a decent source of random numbers consider using something like the Mersenne Twister. Seeding from time can also have problems under highly sensitive situations (e.g. online gambling, etc.).